# Azure Point to Site VPN connection from IOS / IPad / IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, ipad, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to connect from an IOS device to an Azure Point to Site VPN? (Yes, I know it is unsupported). However, I have seen it suggested that SSTP could be used, but cant find a concrete example.

Can anyone shed some light on if this is actually possible - or suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

---

**Now, Azure P2S VPN can be configured on iOS.**

How to:

iOS VPN clients are supported for the Resource Manager deployment model only. They are not supported for the classic deployment model.

> Note IKEv2 is currently in Preview.

When installing a client certificate, you need the password that was created when the client certificate was exported.

1. Locate the `.pfx` certificate file and copy it to your iOS. You can get the certificate to the iOS in several ways, for example, you can email the certificate file or copy it to your Onedrive and open it through Safari. Click Allow

[image]

2. Install the certificate on your iOS:

[image][image]

[image][image]

3. Adding VPN configuration on iOS (Choose to use certificate to authentication,details information is in the **VpnSettings.xml**, which downloaded from Azure portal > Point-to-site configuration> Download VPN client> Open the folder > Generic ):

[image][image]

4.Connect the VPN and try browse the IIS behind the Azure VNet via a private IP:

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks Wayne. It's good to get a concrete answer. I'll leave the question open a while longer for any other options and if none arise I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: HI, @MurrayFoxcroft. I test it again and succeed. Cheers!  Azure P2S VPN can be configured on iOS. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Wayne.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft , Cheers!

Comment: Configuring VPN servers and clients is not programming. Do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: To get this to work for me, I had to set "Local ID" to the UPN contained in the client cert. Using the Subject or CN didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not supported. You can leave your feedback and upvote for the same in this feedback link - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/4233968-either-add-point-to-site-sstp-vpn-clients-for-mac

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to force native VPN in iPhone to work with Azure VPN (IKEv2, certificate authentication), but I succeed with OpenVPN type of tunnel and an external app.
Generally the whole setup procedure is described in [Configure point-to-site VPN clients: certificate authentication - macOS and iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-cert-mac#openvpn-ios-steps) in section "OpenVPN: iOS steps"

However there are few things that needs to be done differently:

1. Current version of OpenVPN Connect app does not work on iPhone/iPad anymore with Azure VPN and there is no possibility to install previous version. The only application does work for me was "Passepartout, VPN Clinet". This app works also with .ovpn configuration files in the same way as OpenVPN Connect.
2. There is missing information how to get the private key from the .pfx file. This can be done on macOS with the following command: `openssl pkcs12 -in P2SChildCert.pfx -nocerts -out priv-key.pem -nodes`
3. When copying client certificate and private key into .ovpn file they need to be copied WITH certificate headers

The rest of the steps can be found in [Configure server settings for P2S VPN Gateway connections - certificate authentication - Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal).